# what is the fastest way to draw pixel in win32

Tags: c++, winapi, 3d, renderer, doublebuffered

I'm writting a simple software renderer,
load 3d model, process vertex, rasterization, texture, lighting,
all that things, all done.
I used SDL(not using OpenGL mode) to draw pixel on its SDL_Surface,
and call SDL_Flip, so one frame appears.

for some reason now I don't want to use SDL,
I just need a double-buffer to draw pixel.

I know there're someway to do this,
OpenGL, Direct3D, gdi,
maybe they're too "advanced" for this project,
what is the direct(or fastest) way to draw pixels to back-buffer on win32 ?

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using a graphics API for this (OpenGL or Direct3D), but GDI would be the easiest option. You can create a DIB (Device Independent Bitmap) using the `CreateDIBSection` function which returns a pointer to the bitmap's memory. You can then modify the pixels of the bitmap however you please and draw it to your window's client area. See chapter 15 of *Programming Windows* (5th) by Charles Petzold for source code and explanation of this technique.

Comment: in that case you need to use either OpenGL or DirectX. DirectX may be easier for you to get started with, though personally I'd favour OpenGL.